# Refresh Browser During Visual Studio Debug or Build

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Rather than have visual studio open a new browser or tab every time you hit debug is it possible to just refresh the currently opened tab or browser?

I see that in web.config->Web there is the option to not open a page, but that is only half the battle. How do we trigger the browser refresh. Too good to be true?

Also is there a way to make stop debugging something other than shift+f5.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the currently opened browser should reload your new code without any problem. If you are using a web application project type; you will need to recompile to see changes made to your codebehind; but you shouldn't need to start the debugger each time.

Comment: I am using MVC so I have to build the project to see changes. so a browser refresh would also be helpful during a build